# TortoiseSVN: Can I stop inheritance of svn:ignore properties?

Tags: inheritance, properties, tortoisesvn, ignore, svnignore

I only want to ignore a single file in a single folder.

But all my subfolders inherits that svn:ignore property.

I didn't use 'recursively'.

I don't want to ignore all files with that name in the whole folder tree.

What about a file like 'logfile.txt' ?

I would like to ignore it in a parent folder, but not in all subfolders.

Of course, I could add the other files, but why I can't control the inheritance here ?

I just would like to keep the unversioned overlay symbol on same named files in the subfolders.